# How can I get the value of charging current (in mA) in an android application?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to measure the value of current(mA) during the charging of Android phone. 
How can I read the current and display it in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the current on the battery using the [BatteryManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW) class and then the `BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW` property.

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
val mBatteryManager = this.getSystemService(Context.BATTERY_SERVICE) as BatteryManager
val current = mBatteryManager.getLongProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW).div(1000)
```

*Keep in mind that this might not work on some devices like samsung, realme, huawei.*